# Redering HTML in blade template from shortcut IF statement

Tags: php, laravel-blade

Okay so I have the following (multiple times) in my blade template:

```
{{ Auth::user()->settings['font'] == null ? "<span class='fa fa-check'></span>" : false }}
```

However it doesnt render the span statement, it simply prints it out.  I've read elsewhere that to render HTML in a blade template I need to use `{!! <span></span> !!}` but how can I do that within a shortcut IF statement?

Comment: Hm, don't your other .blade templates print out HTML without using `{!! !!}`?? What's wrong with using `@if`?

Answer (score 2):

The `{{ $thing }}` syntax escapes the content passed to it via the [`e()` helper](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php#L574). You can use the following alternative syntax: `{!! $thing !!}`

This syntax works the same as the first one so you can use your ternary condition too. The following will print nothing if the condition is not met.

```
{!! Auth::user()->settings['font'] == null ? "<span class='fa fa-check'></span>" : '' !!}
```

Alternatively with `@if`:

```
@if(Auth::user()->settings['font'] == null)
    <span class='fa fa-check'></span>
@endif
```

Comment: Missing `@endif`?

Comment: Indeed, I fix that. Thank you.